# I can't find the memory link which valgrind told me

Tags: c++

I'm writing a linked list, and a function which to append a new value into it, here is my code:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct ListNode {
        int m_value;
        ListNode *m_next;
        ListNode () {}
        ListNode(int i) {
            m_value = i;
            m_next = NULL;
        }
    };

    void append(int const value, ListNode *head) {
        ListNode *list = new ListNode(value);
        if (head != NULL) {
            while (head->m_next != NULL) {
                head = head->m_next;
            }
            head->m_next = list;
        } else {
            head = list;
        }
    }

    void print(ListNode *head) {
        while (head != NULL) {
            cout << head->m_value << endl;
            head = head->m_next;
        }
    }

    int main() {
        ListNode *list = new ListNode(1);
        append(2, list);
        append(3, list);
        append(4, list);
        append(5, list);

        print(list);

        delete list;
}
```

Then I used valgrind to check memory leak, use this command:

```sh
    valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --trace-children=yes ./listnodes
```

It showed:

```sh
  64 (16 direct, 48 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
  at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
  by 0x108B1D: append(int, ListNode*) (in /home/qihao/c/test/listnodes/listnodes/listnodes)
  by 0x108968: main (in /home/qihao/c/test/listnodes/listnodes/listnodes)

  LEAK SUMMARY:
  definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
  indirectly lost: 48 bytes in 3 blocks
  possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

  ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

There is one leak. I can't tell where the leak happened in my codes, could anyone help? thanks.

Comment: Do you build with debug information (adding the `-g` flag when building)? Then Valgrind will be able to give you filename and line-number information.

Comment: You should avoid raw pointers and naked `new` / `delete`. Use smart pointers. In append is a `new`. Where do you delete these objects and free the memory?

Comment: And generally, you need to match *each* `new` with a corresponding `delete`. If you do multiple `new` then you need multiple `delete`.

Comment: Also remember that in C++ arguments are by default passed *by value*. That means the value is *copied* into the functions argument variable. And modifying the argument variable (for example by assignment) will not change the original value. Think about that when you assign to `head` in the `append` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only delete the head of your list. With each call to the `append` function, you create a new node. At the end of your program you must delete all nodes, try to do something like this instead:

```cpp
int main()
{
    ListNode *list = new ListNode(1);
    append(2, list);
    append(3, list);
    append(4, list);
    append(5, list);

    print(list);

    ListNode *tmp1 = list;
    ListNode *tmp2;
    while (tmp1 != NULL)
    {
        tmp2 = tmp1->m_next;
        delete tmp1;
        tmp1 = tmp2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete). Use smart pointers. In `append` is a `new`. You don't delete these objects and free the memory. That's the memory leak.

I changed your code from using raw pointers to using smart pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct ListNode {
    int m_value;
    std::unique_ptr<ListNode> m_next;
    ListNode () = default;
    ListNode(int i) : m_value(i) {}
};

void append(int const value, ListNode *head) {
    if (head != nullptr) {
        while (head->m_next != nullptr) {
            head = head->m_next.get();
        }
        head->m_next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(value);
    }
}

void print(ListNode *head) {
    while (head != nullptr) {
        std::cout << head->m_value << '\n';
        head = head->m_next.get();
    }
}

int main() {
    auto list = std::make_unique<ListNode>(1);
    append(2, list.get());
    append(3, list.get());
    append(4, list.get());
    append(5, list.get());

    print(list.get());
}
```

The functionality should be the same but now you don't have to worry about cleaning up the memory. You should note that in both versions of this code `head` in

```
void append(int const value, ListNode *head)
```

has to be pointing to a valid `ListNode` object. Otherwise the list will stay empty.

You can fix this using a reference to `head`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct ListNode {
    int m_value;
    std::unique_ptr<ListNode> m_next;
    ListNode () = default;
    ListNode(int i) : m_value(i) {}
};

void append(int const value, std::unique_ptr<ListNode> &head) {
    if (!head) {
        head = std::make_unique<ListNode>(value);
        return;
    }
    auto temp = head.get();
    while (temp->m_next != nullptr) {
        temp = temp->m_next.get();
    }
    temp->m_next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(value);
}

void print(ListNode *head) {
    while (head != nullptr) {
        std::cout << head->m_value << '\n';
        head = head->m_next.get();
    }
}

int main() {
    //auto list = std::make_unique<ListNode>(1);
    std::unique_ptr<ListNode> list;
    append(2, list);
    append(3, list);
    append(4, list);
    append(5, list);

    print(list.get());
}
```

It's unrelated but I recommend to read [Should I use using namespace std in my code?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std)